# Magnolia - Cross field validation

Tags: magnolia

We have below requirement.

Field 1 : comboBoxField and it is mandatory.

Field 2:  comboBoxField

Case 1. If editor choose field 1 value is "value1", then field 2 is mandatory

Case 2: if editor choose Field  1 value is "value2", then filed 2 is optional.

How to do this validation either in form/field validation before commit action.

Or how do we validate in commit action.

Any lead will help me a lot. I am stuck in this issue for longtime.

I tried with cross-field, dynamic filed , switchable and composite field as suggested in documentation, but I got null pointer exceptions. If you know the solution please share code snippet also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also suffered with this type of validation. The problem is in the isolation of the fields. I couldn't find a way to validate one field depending on another field value.

Anyway I found a workaround solution. I aggregate two dependent fields with complex field and create a validator for it.

Here's my code for the Magnolia 5.7 and vaadin validator (it's deprecated 7th  version, nevertheless the logic will be the same with the 8th version).

```
public class CompanyRequiredFieldsValidator implements Validator {

    private final ConfiguredFieldValidatorDefinition definition;

    public CompanyRequiredFieldsValidator(ConfiguredFieldValidatorDefinition definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object value) throws InvalidValueException {
        Optional<String> companyName = getString(value, "companyName");
        if (companyName.isPresent()) {
            getString(value, "companyAddress")
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidValueException(definition.getErrorMessage()));
        }
    }

    private Optional<String> getString(Object value, String property) {
        return Optional.of(value)
                .filter(Item.class::isInstance).map(Item.class::cast)
                .map(_v -> _v.getItemProperty(property))
                .map(Property::getValue)
                .filter(String.class::isInstance).map(String.class::cast)
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty);
    }

}
```

For complex fields validated value has **com.vaadin.v7.data.Item** type, so it's possible to get all properties from it.

The only problem, that the error message does not highlight the inner field, only whole complex field.

Comment: thank you for the solution. We tried with different approach. When user clicks on save button in UI, we handled validations by reading form view data of those fields and show them alert message with appropriate message.